# Docker. npm install -> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, dns, docker, npm

Why I can not receive the packages node.js in Docker. I get the following message:

```
Step 10 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 20f3e58dea20
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@2.14.7
npm info using node@v4.2.3
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/amqp
npm info attempt registry request try #2 at 3:40:26 PM
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
```

Comment: looks like it fails to connect to registry because of internet connection failing or not connected at all

Comment: @GeoPhoenix with the Internet all right and out of the container `npm i` works but` dockeк "build` `npm i` does not work

Answer (score 2):

For some reason there a problem with the version of Nodier: latest (5.3). Version node with the 4.2 a good worked. WTF?